# logical check of vector values at the same precesion or not

Tags: r, diff, logical-operators, digit

I have a vector with variable elements in it, and I want to check whether it's last two element are in the same digit order.

For example, if the last two vectors are 0.0194 and 0.0198 return `TRUE`. because their digit order after zero is the same (0.01 order 10^-2). ! for other example the number could be 0.00014 and 0.00012 so their precision is still around the same the function should return also `TRUE`.

How can we build a logical statement or function to check this.

```
x<- c(0.817104, 0.241665, 0.040581, 0.022903, 0.019478, 0.019846)
```

Comment: @rawr ok I edited.

Comment: you mean you want to see if the first non zero digit in both are ordered assuming they have the same place value? so `c(0.019,  0.011)` is true and `c(0.01, 0.001)` is false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be over-thinking this, but you can test that the order of magnitude and first non-zero digit are identical for each.

```
x <- c(0.817104, 0.241665, 0.040581, 0.022903, 0.019478, 0.019846)

oom <- function(x, base = 10) as.integer(ifelse(x == 0, 0, floor(log(abs(x), base))))
oom(x)
# [1] -1 -1 -2 -2 -2 -2

(tr <- trunc(x / 10 ** oom(x, 10)))
# [1] 8 2 4 2 1 1
```

So for the last two, the order of magnitude for both is -2 and the first non-zero digit is 1 for both.

Put into a function:

```
f <- function(x) {
  oom <- function(x, base = 10) as.integer(ifelse(x == 0, 0, floor(log(abs(x), base))))
  x <- tail(x, 2)
  oo <- oom(x)
  tr <- trunc(x / 10 ** oo)
  (oo[1] == oo[2]) & (tr[1] == tr[2])
}

## more test cases
x1 <- c(0.019, 0.011)
x2 <- c(0.01, 0.001)

f(x)  ## TRUE
f(x1) ## TRUE
f(x2) ## FALSE
```

Here is a more general function than the above for checking the last `n` instead of 2

```
g <- function(x, n = 2) {
  oom <- function(x, base = 10) as.integer(ifelse(x == 0, 0, floor(log(abs(x), base))))
  x <- tail(x, n)
  oo <- oom(x)
  tr <- trunc(x / 10 ** oo)
  Reduce(`==`, oo) & Reduce(`==`, tr)
}

g(c(.24, .15, .14), 2)  ## TRUE
g(c(.24, .15, .14), 3)  ## FALSE
```

Comment: it is ok for now. I also need to think more. Maybe I should said last two value if comparable return `TRUE`

Comment: @Alexander what do you mean by comparable?

Comment: what I mean by that they are identical to each other. say 0.01 and 0.015 are identical but 0.01 and 0.0010 is not.

Comment: `g` function says could not find function `oo`!

Comment: @Alexander I don't get that, how did you call `g`? `f(c(0.01, 0.015))` is true and `f(c(0.01, 0.0010))` is false, isn't that what should happen?

Comment: I did `g(c(.24, .15, .14), 2)` and gave that error.

Comment: @Alexander do you have `oom` defined? or you can put it inside the `g` function to make it self-contained, see edit

Answer (score 2):

@rawr worries about over-thinking. I guess I should as well. This is what I came up with and do note that this handles the fact that print representations of floating point numbers are sometimes deceiving.

```
orddig <- function(x) which( sapply( 0:16, function(n){ isTRUE(all.equal(x*10^n ,  
                                                                   round(x*10^n,0)))}))[1]
> sapply( c(0.00014 , 0.00012 ), orddig)
[1] 6 6
```

My original efforts were with the signif function but that's a different numerical thought trajectory, since 0.01 and 0.001 have the same number of significant digits. Also notice that:

```
> sapply( 10^5*c(0.00014 , 0.00012 ), trunc, 4)
[1] 13 12
```

Which was why we need the `isTRUE(all.equal(... , ...))`